# Preventing image duplicates on server

Tags: php, image, mysqli, md5

I have a form where the user enters data and uploads an image. This image will be checked if there is an image that is exactly the same using md5 hashing. Each image that is uploaded will have its own md5 hash code. If a user decides to upload an image that is exactly like the one on the server, then that image will not be moved. Instead, when creating the entry, the image will inherit the name of that file from the different entry with the same hash code. But I am running into several problems with my current code. For one, when the user uploads an image for the first time, there is no hash code. Another problem I am experiencing with my code is that even when I upload an image with the same hash code, the name of the image is changing to a uniqid. It is executing the else block and not the if block.

Here's my code:

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["pageNum"], $_FILES["image"], $_POST["subtitle"], $_POST["text"]))
    {
        $page = $_POST["pageNum"];
        $url = $_SESSION["articleUrl"];
        $subtitle = filter_data($_POST["subtitle"]);
        $text = filter_data($_POST["text"]);

        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $tempName = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

        $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";

        $hash = md5_file($target_file);
        $resultHash = $db->query("SELECT * COUNT(*) FROM `Stories` WHERE hash = '$hash' LIMIT 1");

        if ($resultHash->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $row = $resultHash->fetch_array();
            $name = $row["image"];

        }

        else
        {
            if (@getimagesize($target_file) == true)
                    {
                        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     
                        $name = basename($name, "." . $ext);
                        $name = $name . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
                        $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
                    }

            move_uploaded_file($tempName, $target_file);
        }

        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Stories WHERE page = '$page' AND url = '$url'");

        if ($result->num_rows == 0)
        {
            $db->query("INSERT INTO `Stories` (`image`, `text`, `url`, `subtitle`, `page`, `hash`) VALUES ('$name', '$text', '$url', '$subtitle', '$page', '$hash')");
        }

        else
        {
            $db->query("UPDATE Stories SET image = '$name', text = '$text', url = '$url', subtitle = '$subtitle', page = '$page', hash = '$hash' WHERE url = '$url' AND page = '$page'");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines below are problematic because you will only get a hash if the `$target_file` already exists. If there is no file by that name, then there is nothing to hash and you can't get a hash to compare against the DB value.

```
$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
$hash = md5_file($target_file);
```

The first line is useless; remove it. You should be calculating the hash of the newly uploaded file instead because that's what needs to be compared to the hashes stored in the DB:

```
$hash = md5_file($tempName);
```

Later, you also need to change your `getimagesize` check to work with the newly uploaded file because this is the file that needs to be processed (we get to this check if this is a new, unique file):

```
if (getimagesize($tempName) == true)
```

Comment: When I upload the image for the first time, the getimagesize is being invoked for some reason (even though the file is not on the server). Also, when I upload the same image a second time, the if block to check if there are any rows with the hash name, is not being invoked.

Comment: I've made a few changes since first posting. Could you test again with my latest recommendations? Might be helpful to add some `echo` or `vardump` calls at key places to get an idea of what PHP is seeing during execution

Comment: Yes even with the changes I'm getting the same outcome. When I use the $target_file instead of the $tempName in the getimagesize, it's working correctly and not changing the image name when I upload it for the first time

Comment: `$target_file` early in the script is the name of a possibly previously saved file by the same name right?

Comment: $target_file is the destination of where the file should be saved. So at the beginning, $name is the file of the uploaded image. So `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";` will change accordingly. I changed my SQL to `$db->query("SELECT * FROM Stories WHERE hash = $hash LIMIT 1");` and it worked successfully. Everything is working in order now. The only problem is that what if the user uploads an image, and then decides to upload another image, but yet again decides to upload the same image. Then that means the file will be on the server twice

Comment: But I guess, if I do a deletion of that file, that file might be connected with another user's file and I don't want to delete that file...So I don't think there is a solution for this problem

Comment: @RyanVincent I actually got it to work. If the user uploads the image, then it'll be on the server. If the user uploads another image, then I initiate an SQL to check if the previous hash entry matches any of the entries in the database, if there are no entries that match the hash entry then it is safe to delete. The new entry (upload name and hash) takes the places of the previous entry. So far I haven't noticed any errors yet